# JSON.parse() on Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

When I turned on the server, it stops if the function `JSON.parse()` failed to use. Is there any other way to get the return value  of `JSON.parse()`? I want to throw the error when the function doesn't work. When I import data that is not in JSON format, I want to ignore the error in the function.

Comment: JSON.parse will throw an error if the json string is not valid already. to handle errors use try/catch .

Comment: Why were you expecting JSON.parse to parse something that isn't JSON?

Comment: I believe their issue is that the input file may not always be valid JSON. Sounds like a simple `try...catch` will accomplish what they need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a `try...catch` statement.

> The try...catch statement marks a block of statements to try, and specifies a response, should an exception be thrown.

---

For example, the following code snippet will attempt to parse invalid JSON.

```js
const jsonImportedData = 'not valid JSON';

try { 
  JSON.parse(jsonImportedData);
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

If you look at the console, you'll see a log with the `JSON.parse` error message; however, your program will not throw an actual error since it was gracefully handled.